# Updateing NText causing long delay/timeouts

Tags: asp-classic, sql-server-2000, ado

I'm trying to update an NText field in SQL 2000 using Classic ASP. Here is the code I'm using to do it. Any one have any pointers on how to maybe speed it up? Or am I stuck with it.

```
set Cnn = server.CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
Cnn.ConnectionString = Application("Cnn_ConnectionString")
Cnn.open 
set rs = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

rs.CursorType = adoOpenDynamic
rs.LockType = adLockOptimistic      
conChunkSize = 100   
rs.Open "MyTable",Cnn, , , adCmdTable 
rs.Find "MyDataId=" & request("DataId"),,adSearchForward,1     

lngOffset = 0   
lngLogoSize = len(request("txtMyEntry"))*2
Do while lngOffset < lngLogoSize
    varChunk = LeftB(RightB(request("txtMyEntry"), lngLogoSize - _
               lngOffset), conChunkSize)
        rs("MyDataField").AppendChunk varChunk
        lngOffset = lngOffset + conChunkSize
    Loop

rs.Update
rs.Close
```

Oh and this code is almost verbatim from the [MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905922(SQL.80).aspx).

Comment: It would help you specified just how much data you are actually writing to the field.

Comment: The data is just text, any where from 200 to 300 characters all the way up to 10 or 12k.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would eliminate the chunking which is so 90's.

Then there is:-

```
rs.Open "MyTable",Cnn, , , adCmdTable 
rs.Find "MyDataId=" & request("DataId"),,adSearchForward,1
```

Yikes!  You'd like to think that ADO intelligently asked SQL server to find that record based on the indexed MyDataId field but bet it doesn't.  Its most likely pulling the entire contents of the table across until the record is arrived at.

This really should be done with an UPDATE T-SQL statement and an ADODB.Command object.

```
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
cmd.CommandType = 1 '' // adCmdText
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE MyTable SET MyDataField = ? WHERE MyDataId = ?"
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("dataField", 203, 1, Len(txtMyEntry), txtMyEntry)  '' // 203 = asLongVarWChar, 1 = adParamInput
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("id", 3, 1, , CInt(DataID)) '' // 3 = adInteger
cmd.Execute
```

Comment: I'd be willing to be part of the issue is exactly that. Not really sure I understand your sample code, but I'll give it a shot tomorrow.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help on this. I did have to make one small change to it though. I had to change the CInt(), it just Int(), as it was causing an overflow. Though even using it as a string it still accepted it. Thanks again.